# How to get count in views when group by some field?

Tags: 7, views

I have view which display results based on taxonomy field grouping:

[image]

And results look like below :

[image]

I am trying to display count of each group in brackets next to Topic field, Is that possible to achieve with this kind of view. Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this module

[Term Node Count](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_node_count)

Comment: I want to list nodes as well but do not want to show only count. count is possible by doing aggregation. But I am just displaying list of nodes  which are grouped by term and for each group want to display count at top of grouped title. any other ideas ?